# Linux centos 6.5 Disk performance monitoring using smartctl

Tags: linux, centos6, smartctl

i installed smartctl utility in centos 6.7 but cant get output of smartctl ,                                                  i fire

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 5.43 2016-09-28 r4347 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               VMware 
Product:              Virtual disk
Revision:             1.0
User Capacity:        858,993,459,200 bytes [858 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sat May 27 15:16:54 2017 IST
```

Device does not support SMART? does anyone having idea to resolve this ?

Comment: what is it you wish to get resolved? Disk performance monitoring? Smartctl is not the tool for that anyway how about sysstat (iostat, sar) or some benchmarking tool like iozone or bonnie++ ?

Answer (score 1):

You run `smartctl` on Virtual Machine inside VMWare ESXi environment. Virtual disk - is file on storage and it not support SMART.